# Improving RadFileUpload to check for 250MB file size BEFORE starting Upload?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Can anyone tell me how you would check the File Size of the file selected to upload BEFORE starting the upload?

```
<telerik:RadUpload ID="fuUploadFile" runat="server" ControlObjectsVisibility="None"
    OnClientFileSelected="validationFailed" InputSize="50" TargetFolder="\Upload" AllowedFileExtensions=".wav,.mp3,.mpeg,.mpg,.wmv,.avi,.mp4" />
<telerik:RadProgressArea ID="RadProgressArea1" runat="server" BackColor="#668B8B"
    ToolTip="Uploading " >
</telerik:RadProgressArea>
<telerik:RadProgressManager ID="RadProgressManager1" runat="server"  />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorUploadFile" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
    ClientValidationFunction="validateFile" CssClass="RedItalic1" Text="... error text here" />
```

Comment: That is a problem. That I know of, you can not do a client side check of a file and it's size. Major security issues there letting a browser script do file IO. And obviously, the server cannot validate the size until it has the file. This is a broad weak spot in file uploading.

Answer (score 1):

Create a handler.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpPostedFile up = context.Request.Files[0];
    if(up.ContentLength > 2097152)    // 2MB
    {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RadAsyncUpload because it offers this OOB: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/validation/defaultcs.aspx